# Function will not call Swift 3

Tags: swift, function, swift3, handler, completion

```
@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {

    print("began signup process")

    guard let fullname = fullnameField.text, fullname != "" else {
        print("FULLNAME field is empty")
        return
    }

    guard let username = usernameField.text, username != "" else {
        print("USERNAME field is empty")
        return
    }

    guard let email = emailField.text, email != "" else {
        print("EMAIL field is empty")
        return
    }

    guard let password = passwordField.text, password != "" else {
        print("PASSWORD field is empty")
        return
    }

    print("all fields good")

    mainActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    self.checkUsernameAvailability(username: username, completion: {
        result in
        print("starting check")
        ...
    })


    print("finished the function")
}
```

The issue is basically that nothing inside of the checkUsernameAvailability function will call.
The console looks like this:

```
began signup process
all fields good
finished the function
```

it does not print 'starting check' or run any code at all inside of the function.
This is probably a rookie error and I am sorry if it is a stupid question.
Future thanks.

P.S I checked the entire console and there is no error relating to this.

EDIT: Here is the code inside the function

```
func checkUsernameAvailability(username: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    _ = Database.database().reference().child("usernames").observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in

        print("checking username availability")
        print(snapshot)

        completion(true)

        let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        for handled in (dict?.values)! {

            print("stumbled")
            print(handled)
            if username.lowercased() == handled.lowercased {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And...

```
self.checkUsernameAvailability(username: username, completion: {
        result in

        print("starting check")

        if result == false {
            print("username is taken")
            self.mainActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            return
        } else {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {
                (user, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error ?? "ERROR OCCURED")
                    self.mainActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    return
                }

                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                ref.child("~/users/\(user?.uid ?? "0")/username").setValue(username.lowercased())
                ref.child("~/users/\(user?.uid ?? "0")/fullname").setValue(fullname)
                ref.child("usernames/\(user?.uid ?? "0")").setValue(username.lowercased())

                self.mainActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })

        }
    })
```

Comment: Please post the code of `checkUsernameAvailability`, too. Strictly spoken the text in the closure is supposed to be `"finishing check"`.

Comment: If `"checking username availability"` is not printed there is something wrong with the database call. I'm sure the database API provides code to check if an error occurred. And you should call  `completion(true/false)` only once in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Database.database().reference().child("usernames").observe` call simply never calls the `with` block. I would assume that block is called when the event `.childAdded` is observed, but I see no code that would add a child. To me this looks like you are setting up an asynchronous observer, so this code will not run when you make the call, it will run when the monitored event takes place.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this was such a stupid mistake. I forgot to change it as I copied and pasted from another example rather than remaking.